# Spark - Print log when everything is complete

Tags: java, apache-spark

Small question regarding Spark please.

I am trying to achieve something quite straightforward, print a log statement when **everything** is complete.

Meaning, the job is complete, all operations are complete, a compete shut down, etc...

Therefore, I tried adding the log statement at the end, like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String query = "(SELECT top 10000000000 from [...]";
        final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
        final Properties   connectionProperties   = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.putAll([...]);
        final Dataset<Row> bigDataSet = sparkSession.read().jdbc(someUrl, veryBigTable, connectionProperties);

        final Dataset<String> bigDataSetAfterMap = bigDataSet.map((MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> someVeryHeavyLongOperation(row), Encoders.STRING());

        bigDataSetAfterMap.count();
        sparkSession.stop();
        System.out.println("application stop - all processing complete - the whole job is done - this should be printed at the very end when everything is done, job shut down");
        
    }
```

I am sure the table I select is very big.

I am sure the operations I need to perform are also very heavy, and time consuming.

I have KPIs, metrics etc proving the method `someVeryHeavyLongOperation` is still ongoing.

What I expect, was to see all operations complete, and then, some sort of final line, my log statement.

However, I see my log statement long before completion.

I am wondering, how to print a log statement proving everything is complete from the Spark job?

Thank you

Comment: move the line `sparkSession.stop();` before System.out.println.

Comment: Wrong copy paste, question edited, it was already the last line

Comment: could you share the log information? just highlight what is being printed